# How to Define a One-Side-Optional One-to-One Relationship in SQL Server and LINQ-to-SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql, linq-to-sql, one-to-one, cardinality

I am trying to create a one-to-one relationship that is optional on one side between a User table and a UserInfo table.  The specifications are that a UserInfo must have exactly one User, while a User can have one or zero UserInfos.  Also we require that the foreign key exist in the UserInfo table so that the columns of the User table are not modified.  We would like to use the relationship in C# LINQ-to-SQL, e.g., `user.UserInfo.Email = "test@test.com",`userInfo.User`, etc.

The T-SQL for the tables and the foreign key from UserInfos to Users is (roughly):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users](
    [UserId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Username] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Users] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [UserId] ASC ),
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserInfos](
    [UserInfoId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Email] [varchar](250) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_UserInfo] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [UserInfoId] ASC ),
    CONSTRAINT [UQ_UserId] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ( [UserId] ASC )
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserInfos]  WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_UserInfos.UserID_Users.UserId] FOREIGN KEY([UserId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([UserId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserInfos] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_UserInfos.UserID_Users.UserId]
GO
```

The problem is that if I define a foreign key from Users.UserId (the primary key) to UserInfos.UserId (which is, I understand, the correct way to define a *non-optional* one-to-one relationship) then performing the LINQ-to-SQL code `user.UserInfo = null` also sets the `user.UserId` to `default(int)`.

Here is the T-SQL I use to define the foreign key between `Users` and `UserInfos`:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Users]  WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Users.UserId_UserInfos.UserId] FOREIGN KEY([UserId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[UserInfos] ([UserId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Users] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Users.UserId_UserInfos.UserId]
GO
```

If I do not define this foreign key, then I get no LINQ-to-SQL property on a `User` allowing me to access the `UserInfo`.  How can I have a relationship between the table `Users` and `UserInfos` that is traversable with LINQ-to-SQL, while at the same time allowing this relationship to be null from the `User` side?  Thank you.

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921788/linq-2-sql-one-to-zero-or-one-relationship-possible) without acceptable answer

Comment: It's not a duplicate; that question is asking how to model this relationship in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this but you're approaching it from the wrong side.

When you call

```
user.UserInfo = null;
```

the exception states that

> An attempt was made to remove a relationship between a User and a UserInfo. However, one of the relationship's foreign keys (UserInfo.UserId) cannot be set to null.

LINQ-to-SQL thinks you are trying to remove the relationship between the two items; and in an indirect way you are. But the exception is just a reiteration of what you've stated yourself - a `UserInfo` must have a `User`. You're unlinking the two objects but you aren't removing the `UserInfo` - you're leaving an orphaned `UserInfo` in your context which cannot be persisted to the database (due to the foreign key constraint).

The answer? Delete the `UserInfo`.

```
var user = context.Users.First();
var userinfo = user.UserInfos;
user.UserInfos = null;
context.UserInfos.DeleteOnSubmit(userinfo);
context.SubmitChanges();

// or, even simpler:
var user = context.Users.First();
context.UserInfos.DeleteOnSubmit(user.UserInfos);
context.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks.  For starters, I think I was defining the relationship incorrectly.  By creating both a foreign key and unique index on the side of the UserInfo, I got the behavior I wanted.  I haven't yet tested whether user.UserInfo = null is a problem now.